Какой предлог использовать в предложение «в» или « на»
Как правильно?
Приглашаем на театральное отделение Подпорожской детской школы искусств
или
Приглашаем в театральное отделение Подпорожской детской школы искусств

Пригласить в театральное отделение, а тем более на театральное отделение вряд ли можно. Предложение стоит перестроить.

приглашаете что делать? в предложении не хватает сказуемого. Приглашаем - это не сказуемое. Да и подлежащего не хватает.

Правильно:
Приглашаем на театральное отделение Подпорожской детской школы искусств.
Сравнить: набираем студентов на факультет/отделение в институт информатики. Предлог НА — отвлеченное значение, Предлог В — конкретное пространственное значение. Также: на уроках в школе.
Пример:
Приглашаем на театральное отделение. В Детской школе искусств им. Н.Г. Рубинштейна объявляется набор на внебюджетные места на театральном отделении.
